# For mobile app developer, which screen size is the most common one?

Tags: mobile-application, screen-resolution

Currently, I'm designing a mobile app -using hybrid platform- for public use, and I'd like to know, which screen size I should use as my standard, so I can give the best user experience for my customer.

Answer (score 2):

What's your product for? Do you have targeted an audience of users yet? Where do they live, what do they do, how are they interacting with your product?

I wouldn't necessarily decide on this upon "most used screen size".

I personally would think about the product, its placement on the market and my target audience first. Age, country, local internet speeds play a huge role when deciding upon designs especially on mobile.

The best experience does not come from a single most used device or screen size, but rather from an experience that works on any device you're targeting.

Comment: 'but rather from an experience that works on any device you're targeting.' Very, very, very important.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could see here the 2016 stats for all smart devices: https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-used-smartphone-screen-resolutions-in-2016

You can see it also by country and choose the exact case you want.